# Modify class SphericalGLSurfaceview

Tags: java, exoplayer, 360-virtual-reality

I was trying to use Exoplayer to reproduce a 360 video with a separated view for each eye, the google developers on GitHub told me that i have to modify SphericalGLSurfaceView, forking the file and any files it depends on that I need to modify. But I dont know how to display the 2 views and there are so many libraries to fork. There is an easier way to do this?